# Specify "numbering plan indicator" in SMSLib JSMPPGateway

Tags: java, smslib, jsmpp

How can I specify the "Numbering Plan Indicator" when connecting to a SMPP Server with SMSLib (JSMPPGateway).

This is my current JSMPPGateway initialization:

```
gateway = new JSMPPGateway(systemId, ip, port, new BindAttributes(username, password, "smpp_1", BindType.TRANSCEIVER));
```

The problem is that I can't connect to the gateway:

```
IOException: java.io.IOException:
Receive negative bind response: Negative response 0000000f found
```

My provider (the owner of the SMPP server) is telling me that I'm not using the correct Numbering Plan Indicator. **How can I set that parameter?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Set the values of NPI,TON values specified by SMSC in Address params.
```

Ex:

gateway=new JSMPPGateway(systemId, ip, port, new BindAttributes(username, password, "smpp_1", BindType.TRANSCEIVER,new Address(Address.TypeOfNumber.INTERNATIONAL, Address.NumberingPlanIndicator.NATIONAL)));

Comment: where is the quote from? because my JSMPPConstructor wont accept that fourth parameter, neither will BindAttributes

Comment: Thanks!, ended up doing this: gateway.setSourceAddress(new Address(TypeOfNumber.UNKNOWN, NumberingPlanIndicator.ISDN));